# How to Log to RichTextBox using Shared Functions in different Class

Tags: vb.net, logging, richtextbox

what is the best way to display a Log to a RichTextBox while executing Functions, which are defined in another class?

As for now I've tried something like that:

```
Public Class NewClass
    Public Shared Function test(ByRef rtb As RichTextBox)
        rtb.AppendText("logging")
        ''' do something useful and time consuming
        rtb.AppendText("logging")
        ''' do something useful and time consuming
        rtb.AppendText("logging")
  
    End Function
End Class
```

And I executed this function using `NewClass.test(RichTextBox1)` for example.

It is working, and I get the logging output immediately.

But I have many Functions in the "NewClass" and would like to have a central way to make the logging, and write the log to my RichTextBox.

Is there a best practice for doing that?

Thanks a lot in common!

Comment: It's not really clear to me what you're trying to do.

Comment: There are some 3rd part libraries around specifically for logging, might be worth investigating those rather than re-inventing the wheel.  On topic though, what your doing is fine if it does what, as long as you've got a reference to to your RichTextBox available.  Better option might be to switch it around an pass the message into your method that knows about the the RichTextBox